# programmable 3D keyframe animation

Tags: data-visualization, 3d, animation

I need a 3D animation software that fits these criteria:
- able to download 3d models (that I have made in other programs)
- able to take a list of coordinates and move from one to another (keyframe)

I will be given a long list of coordinates an will need to animate a robot (which I have already modeled) to follow these coordinates. I don't know if a program like this exists, but please let me know if you know something that might help.

Answer (score 2):

Seeing your question caused "Blender" to pop into my alleged mind. A quick search for "Blender animation with parameters" resulted in the top return being a [StackExchange answer from the Blender group](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/61614/can-object-parameters-be-set-from-data-file).

I've played a bit with Blender and recognize its power, but also its complexity. This particular link suggests that the files can be read into Blender using an animation nodes add-in, at which point it's well beyond my capability to understand.

I suspect that this will do as you require, however, but suggest that the learning curve will be steep. Perhaps not, for some folks with more active brain cells than I.

[image: bouncy balls]

This image is direct from the above noted link and represents a file of parameters applied to the models.

Comment: My first though too. Never got into Animation Nodes myself but I'm an avid Blender user daily and this would be my response as well

Answer (score 0):

*Most* **3D DCC** (**D**igital **C**ontent **C**reation) programs will do this in one way or another - [**Blender**](https://www.blender.org/) surely will, as would [**Modo**](https://www.foundry.com/products/modo), [**Maya**](https://www.autodesk.com/products/maya/overview), [**3DS**](https://www.autodesk.com/products/3ds-max/overview), or [**C4D**](https://www.maxon.net/en/products/cinema-4d/overview/) - it's down to familiarity and ease of setup for the coordinate import read node.

**[Blender](https://www.blender.org/)** is open-source and freeware, and though the **[Blender](https://www.blender.org/)** UI & learning curve have been notorious for opacity in the past, the recent V2.8 update is *supposed* to be a tectonic shift in **[Blender](https://www.blender.org/)** UI towards ease-of-use and comfortable onboarding. I also recently found the [**BforArtists**](https://www.bforartists.de/) fork, which is a fork of the main Blender development which has been repackaged to have a more artist-friendly, intuitive UI, whilst retaining all main fork [**Blender**](https://www.blender.org/) tools and systems.

Though I started *many* years ago with **[form•Z](http://www.formz.com/products/formzpro.html)** and [**Maya**](https://www.autodesk.com/products/maya/overview), my own *preference* is for [**Modo**](https://www.foundry.com/products/modo) (having been an avid [**Modo**](https://www.foundry.com/products/modo) user now since version 401); powerful but with a manageable initial learning curve, both direct modeling and procedural / parametric modeling tools, excellent animation and dynamics tools, and all that jazz - it is, however, very much *full-cost* professional software; the decision matrix revolves around your comfort in learning something like [**Blender**](https://www.blender.org/), which is powerful, extensible and free, but has a unique and challenging interface, versus something like [**Modo**](https://www.foundry.com/products/modo), which is powerful, extensible, and far more artist friendly and learning friendly, but full cost.